# Throw exceptions from button action function

Tags: button, action

I need to make a tcp/ip communication program and when adding action to my button it says there's unhandled exceptions, but I cannot add throws IOExceptions to the button action function. How to make it work?

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
            int port = Integer.parseInt(txtport.getText());
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            String message = txtsend.getText();
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = listener.accept();
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out =
                            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        out.println(message); } 
                    finally {
                        socket.close();
                    }}}
            finally {
                listener.close();
            }}
        catch(Exception e1){}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `throws Exception` before the function body, but you should rather declare a `catch` block directly in your function. If you're not familiar with try - catch blocks and exceptions, read more info here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch, show the error message to the user, and break out of the loop.

```
catch(Exception e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
     break;
} finally {
     socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Well I made my code like this, but now whenever I press the button the whole program freezes... (see original post code)

Comment: you have an exception at athe end of your code. That should catch everything. Put your cleanup code in the finally, and put an error dialog popup in the catch()